# verbatim useable with a newenvironment definition?

Tags: verbatim, environments

I'm trying to create a simple newenvironment allowing me to display source code in a verbatim text block with a caption, numbering etc. The solution I'm after is with the in-built LaTeX verbatim environment.

I would have used the fancyvrb package, that seems to allow that kind of thing, but I can't update my MiKTeX installation due to proxy authentication issues. Instead I'm after a way to do it *with just the built in verbatim environment*. When I get home, I can adapt it to use fancyvrb (so I am still interested in answers relating to that), but for now, I'm after a temporary solution to get me through the day. ;^)

Here's what I imagine the newenvironment command would be like:

```
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{program}{h}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Example}

\newenvironment{example}[2]{%
    \begin{program}%
    \label{#1}%
    \caption{#2}%
    \scriptsize
    \begin{verbatim}%
}{%
    \end{verbatim}%
    \end{program}%
}
```

It fails later-on, complaining about overfull \hboxes, which I assume means that it's still trying to typeset the rest of my document as though it were in verbatim mode.

Can I use verbatim env in this way? Got a workaround (given that my MiKTeX package repo is pretty small)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{boxed}
\newfloat{program}{h}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Example}

\newbox\examplebox
\newenvironment{example}[2]{%
    \program
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{#1}%
    \verbatim
}{%
    \endverbatim
    \vskip-.7\baselineskip
    \endprogram
}
\begin{document}
\begin{example}{foo}{caption}
foo
bar
baz
\end{example}
\end{document}
```

Note that you need to have the `\label` after the `\caption`. The `\verbatim` macro as reimplemented by the `verbatim` package seems to be looking for `\end{foo}` where `foo` is the name of the current environment. This is why it uses `\program`, `\verbatim`, `\endverbatim`, and `\endprogram`.

The `\vskip` isn't necessary, but you end up with extra space without it.

Comment: Could somebody tell me what this line does? `\newbox\examplebox` and where are these commands defined?