# using fancyvrb Verbatim environment from within newenvironment

Tags: verbatim, fancyvrb

As with this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8419/verbatim-useable-with-a-newenvironment-definition), I want to use a verbatim environment from within an environment definition, but I want the listings to be numbered, so I think I need to use fancyvrb. It appears that fancyvrb has no equivalent to `\verbatim` and `\endverbatim`. I can't see how to use it within an environment definition. Here's what I have (based on verbatim package):

```
\newenvironment{example}[2]{%
    \program%
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{#1}%
    \vskip.7\baselineskip
    \scriptsize
    \verbatim%
}{%
    \endverbatim\normalsize
    \vskip-.5\baselineskip
    \endprogram
}
```

I'd like to use a fancyvrb environment, defined like so:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment%
{Example}{Verbatim}
{numbers=left,fontsize=\scriptsize, stepnumber=3,
frame=lines,framerule=0.8mm}
```

to do this:

```
\newenvironment{example}[2]{%
    \program%
    \caption{#2}%
    \label{#1}%
    \vskip.7\baselineskip
    \scriptsize
    \begin{Example}%
}{%
    \end{Example}\normalsize
    \vskip-.5\baselineskip
    \endprogram
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
  ! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
```

I'm probably doing something silly, but would some patient person point out to me what it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the same is possible with the listing environment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,caption,floatrow}
\DeclareNewFloatType{example}{placement=t,%within=section,
   fileext=exa,name=Example}
\captionsetup[example]{font=sf,labelfont=bf,skip=\smallskipamount}

\newenvironment{Example}[2]
{\VerbatimEnvironment
 \captionof{example}{#2}\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\label{#1}\fi%
\begin{Verbatim}[numbers=left,fontsize=\scriptsize, stepnumber=3,
                 frame=lines,framerule=0.4mm]}
{\end{Verbatim}}

\begin{document}

\begin{Example}{TheLabel}{The caption}
foo
bar
\end{Example}

\begin{Example}{}{Another caption}
foo
bar
baz
\end{Example}

See Example~\ref{TheLabel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly, and has the added advantage that the examples can split nicely across pages.