# verbatim environment or lstlisting as part of newenvironment with samepage and \ill?

Tags: environments, verbatim, fancyvrb

I'd like to make a "codeillustration" environment that's something like:

```
\newenvironment{codeillustration}[1]{
\begin{samepage}
{\ill{#1}}
\VerbatimEnvironment
\begin{Verbatim}{\end{Verbatim}}
\end{samepage}
}
```

An example:

```
\codeillustration{Some great code.}{
  code = 'great'
  print(code)
}
```

would act like

```
\begin{samepage}
{\ill{Some great code.}}
\begin{verbatim}
  code = 'great'
  print(code)
\end{verbatim}
\end{samepage}
```

The `codeillustration` I define above gives the following error:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `{\end {Verbatim}} \end {samepage} {' between \begin{samepag
e}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ... {FancyVerb Error:
\space \space #1
}
```

That likely means I don't know how to program latex macros well.

I saw [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18322/using-fancyvrb-verbatim-environment-from-within-newenvironment) and read some of the [fancyvrb docs](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf), but I'm not seeing what to do.  I can add `samepage=true` to a custom verbatim environment, but it's not obvious how to get in the `\ill` and keep it on the same page.

I'd also be fine with a `lstlisting` example instead of verbatim.  I just want to keep the `\ill` (numbered headline) with the code all on the same page.  These are short code examples in general.

**EDIT**:

I just saw this example in the lstlisting package to get a background color (different question, but shows customizing such a thing):

```
\begin{verbatimwrite}{temp.c}
/* the following code computes $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$ */
for (i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
sum += i;
}
\end{verbatimwrite}
\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=yellow!10, rightline=false]
\lstinputlisting[language=C,mathescape,frame={}]{./temp.c}
\end{mdframed}
```

This makes me want to be able to wrap `lstlisting` into a `newenvironment` as well.

My point is, I just want my own `codeillustration` environment, and to be able to play with the settings without changing the callers.

**EDIT**: Note `\ill` is defined as

```
\newtheorem{ill}{Illustration}[chapter]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're defining an environment and try to use a command. That's not how environments work.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newenvironment{codeillustration}[1]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \par\begin{samepage}
  \begin{ill}#1\end{ill}
  \begin{Verbatim}
 }
 {\end{Verbatim}\end{samepage}}

\newtheorem{ill}{Illustration}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}

\begin{codeillustration}{Some great code}
code = 'great'
print(code)
\end{codeillustration}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks.  Yeah, `\ill` is defined as `\newtheorem{ill}{Illustration}[chapter]` in the `book` document class.

Comment: @dfrankow If you define `ill` with `\newtheorem`, you should *not* use `\ill`, but `\begin{ill}` and `\end{ill}`. I changed the code to use it.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! I'm using code from someone else, and I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: @dfrankow It seems that your friend has very peculiar ideas of what environments are…