# How to automatically escape special characters in your own environment?

Tags: environments, verbatim

I need to create my environment for examples of source codes. I want it to look like this:

**Code example:**

------------------------------------------------

# This is the code example

echo 'Hello'

------------------------------------------------

---

The problem is, that I don't know, how to force it to escape special characters (hash especially) automatically, so the users don't have to type backslash every time they want to write the hash.

---

#### My code

```
\def\terminalText#1\end{\hspace*{2em}\texttt{#1}\\\end}

\newenvironment{codeExample}{
\vspace*{1.5em}
\noindent
Code example:\\
\hspace*{1.3em}\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}\\
\terminalText}
{\hspace*{1.3em}\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}}
```

This code is working well, untill I want to write any special character inside of the environment, then I'm getting this error:

`! Paragraph ended before \terminalText was complete.`

---

I've even tried to make some kind of wrapper to the `verbatim` environment, according to the question [verbatim useable with a newenvironment definition?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8419/verbatim-useable-with-a-newenvironment-definition), but it's giving me this error:

`! LaTeX Error: \begin{codeExample} on input line 535 ended by \end{verbatim}.`

#### My 2nd code

```
\newenvironment{codeExample}{
\vspace*{1.5em}
\noindent
Code Example:\\
\hspace*{1.3em}\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}\\
\verbatim
}
{%
\endverbatim
\hspace*{1.3em}\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}}
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel: Wouldn't the `listings` package be easier to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `verbatim` package the code for the second example works out of the box (if `dashrule` package is included as well)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{dashrule}


\newenvironment{codeExample}{
\vspace*{1.5em}
\noindent
Code Example:\\
\hspace*{1.3em}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}

\verbatim
}
{%
\endverbatim
\hspace*{1.3em}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}
}




\begin{document}

\begin{codeExample}
# This is the code example

echo 'Hello'
\end{codeExample}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please consider `listings` package as a 'better' and cleaner way to typeset code examples.

**Edit** Here's an example with the `tcolorbox` output for listings.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}


\newenvironment{codeExample}{
\vspace*{1.5em}
\noindent
Code Example:\\
\hspace*{1.3em}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}

\verbatim
}
{%
\endverbatim
\hspace*{1.3em}
\hdashrule[0.5ex]{435pt}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}
}


\newtcblisting[auto counter]{codeex}[1][]{%
  arc=0pt,
  auto outer arc,
  colbacktitle=yellow,
  coltitle=black,
  title={Code Example \thetcbcounter},
  listing options={language=bash},
  listing only,
  lowerbox=ignored,
  before upper=\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.9pt}{1.5mm},
  after upper=\hdashrule[0.5ex]{\textwidth}{0.9pt}{1.5mm}
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codeExample}
# This is the code example

echo 'Hello'
\end{codeExample}

\begin{codeex}
echo 'Hello' 

\end{codeex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This one is stille giving me the `! LaTeX Error: \begin{codeExample} on input line 535 ended by \end{verbatim}` error. But you're right, I'll use `listings` package later, it looks great. I had no idea about it before :-)

Comment: Apart from `listings`, there is also the nice `tcolorbox` package which provides nice boxing and breaking of listings etc. But do you have a relatively new TeX distribution? The code above works without problems

Comment: Thank you :-) I have, I think, the problem is maybe caused by TexMaker...

Comment: @MartinBeseda: My experience is, that all those editors cause more problems than using a direct command line compile, therefore I don't use them. Thanks for accepting!